# Create Event Scheduler By Another Event

Tags: mysql

I'm doing mysql event scheduler, but the problem that all events are done by timestamp, i need to create the event by another event

for example when i change a value of attribute in a table, i need to start the event scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *when i change a value of attribute in a table, i need to start the event scheduler*

[***Event Scheduler***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) - is a *calendar time* based event.
It gets fired automatically whenever specified interval change has occurred but *NOT* on any DML operations are performed on a table.

And what you are looking is for an *operation* based event.
It can only be achieved by defining [***Triggers***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html).
Triggers get fired automatically *ONLY when* an associated DML operation is performed on a table.

Difference is that, if an event is scheduled per every 1 hour interval, then the number of times the event fires is only one. Whereas in the case of triggers, for every 1 row affected by any DML operation, it gets fired. The number of calls to trigger, for example in an hour, would be that many DML operations executed during a specific period.